# Creating new data frames from inside a loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame , say "df.1000". I want to break it into 100 smaller data frames.

I don't want to use the subset function manually, e.g. I don't want to type in a 100 times:

```
df.10 <- subset( df.1000, time >=0 & time <10)
df.20 <- subset( df.1000, time >=10 & time <20)

 ...                     ...

df.990 <- subset( df.1000, time >=980 & time <990)
```

So, how can write a loop to create the new data frames without writing their names?

I envision something like:

```
for( k in 1:100){ 
       [create object called "df.k"] <- subset( df.1000, time >=10*(k-1) & time <10*k) 
  }
```

So far, this loop with create an object named, literally df.k, and will not output df.1, df.2, ... df.100

Answer (score 1):

```
for( k in 1:100){ 
   assign(paste("df.", k, sep = ""), subset( df.1000, time >=10*(k-1) & time <10*k))
}
```